# Compiling and linking pimpl style class definition into a library (C++)

Tags: c++, class, pimpl-idiom

I have a class that I use and I tried to rewrite it so it uses the pimpl idiom as an exercise. However, I now have trouble trying to compile and link the program. I have a main folder that contains a folder called `data` in which the pimpl implementation of the class `Data` is declared. This folder again contains a folder `dataimpl` in which the class `DataImpl` is implemented. The tree is

```
├── data
│   ├── dataimpl
│   ├── lib
```

The class `Data` is given as

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_DATA_
#define INCLUDED_DATA_

#include "dataimpl/dataimpl.h"

class Data
{
    DataImpl * pimpl; // Only internal variable

public:
    Data();
    bool read();
    void display() const;
};

#endif
```

I can create an executable like this

```sh
g++-6 main.cc data/*.cc data/dataimpl/*.cc -std=c++14
```

and it works just fine. However, I would like to first create a library file for the `Data` class in the folder `data/lib`. To do this, in the folder `data` I use the commands

```sh
g++-6 -c *.cc
ar -rsv lib/libdata.a
ranlib lib/libdata.a
```

Then I compile the object file for `main.cc` as

```sh
g++-6 -c main.cc
```

Now I want to put the whole thing together by linking as

```sh
g++-6 -o exec main.o data/lib/libdata.a data/dataimpl/*.cc
```

I get the error message

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `Data::Data()'
main.cc:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `Data::read()'
main.cc:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `Data::display() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't understand why the `Data` functions give undefined references as I add the library file to the search path while linking. It would make some sense to me if the `DataImpl` functions are not found, but I add those also the search path (the implementations are in `data/dataimpl` and have `.cc` extensions).

Comment: Just from the first look including `"dataimpl/dataimpl.h"` looks wrong. This include should only be inside `Data.cpp`. In the header you should only use a forward declaration like `class DataImpl`.

Comment: I saw about this forward declaration, however, this should not be causing the problem right? Especially since I can compile it as shown just fine.

Comment: BTW: If you define and implement your `DataImpl` completely inside `Data.cpp`you don't need seperate files for it. And you might want to think about using `std::unique_ptr<DataImpl>` instead of `DataImpl*` to avoid memory leaks

Comment: The problem is that you making the class `DataImpl` visible for everyone that includes `Data.h`.

Comment: This shows a pretty easy way on how to structure data for when using the pimpl idiom: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh438477.aspx

Comment: @SimonKraemer Ah yes, so forward declaration means that the main function never needs to know about the dataimpl class. That is more in line with the philosophy of the pimpl idiom.

Comment: More or less. You should maybe try to create a library for a simple class seperately first. You should only need the header file(s) and the lib itself. If you can get this to work without including any cpp files you might want to change your libraries code to provide a class that hides its private implementation. You should also check out some more examples on pimpl, like http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/pimpl.html

Comment: @SimonKraemer Thanks for the link, I will check it out!

Comment: regardless of the comments about possible poor choices of pointer types and forward declarions, I am still not sure as to why I cannot use the library I created for `Data` class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ar command

```
ar -rsv lib/libdata.a
```

should be

```
ar -rsv lib/libdata.a *.o
```

Otherwise you created an empty archive. BTW you should be familiar with the linux command 'nm' which shows symbols.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I can't believe I forgot something stupid like that. Thanks also for the useful tip on `nm`!